# Dynamic angular content overlaps and goes beyond footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a issue with css in angular while loading the dynamic content.I have a template where i had put my header,content and footer.When i run the application the footer is placed just below the header and the contents that are dynamically added to the content section overlaps the footer and goes beyond the footer section.if I assign a height to container and assign the overflow-y auto to my container section problem is getting solved.But i donot want the scrollbar to my content section as i will be displaying images in my content section which will be lengthy and i want the footer to be at the end of my page .I also dont want the footer to be fixed.I want it such a way that it is displayed below the dynamic content.I have tried flex,calc options too and it is not working out.I have given the code below.Kindly help me out.

### index.html

```
<!doctype  html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MyProj</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="myContainer">
        <div class="myHeader">
            //Some Header Code here
        </div>
        <div ng-view class="myContent">
            //Place where the dynamic content loads
        </div>
        <div class="myFooter">
            //footer content here
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

### CSS

```
.myContainer {
    width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* height: 768px; */
    height:calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.myContent {
    position: relative;
    top: 64px;
    min-height:calc(100% - 150px);
}

.myFooter {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 80px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 1024px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Kindly help me out solving my issue.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could simply do it with normal unstyled div's instead of adding positioning.

```
.myContainer {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.myContent {
    background: lightgreen;
}

.myFooter {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQxYWp

Comment: No i cannot..If i type some static content inside ,yes i will be able to acheive.Since the data loads dynamic it is overlapping the footer